# Какое сочетание клавиш в WebStorm покажет свойства объекта при диструкторизации?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

Знаю что в WebStorm, при диструкторизации объекта, есть сочетание клавиш, которое покажет свойства это объекта,подскажите как оно называется

Comment: вы же сами и написали: называется «сочетание клавиш».

Comment: [WebStorm keyboard shortcuts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/mastering-keyboard-shortcuts.html)

Answer (score 0):

сочетание клавиш `ctrl` / `cmd` + пробел покажет нужное вам, по крайней мере в TS

Comment: не помогло, а как называется эта команда? что бы посмотреть в списке Shortcuts